# tensorflow tensorboard summaries example

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm trying to open a tensorboard using the [example code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_with_summaries.py). I ran the example locally and then tried to open in tensorboard using the following command `tensorboard --logdir=F:\mnist_tmp\tensorflow\mnist\logs\mnist_with_summaries\`.

Tensorboard starts, however I am not able to see any data ie, scalars, graphs, 
 or histograms.

Below is a picture of what I see when I open tensorflow. If I click on the other tabs I get a similar text dialog.
[image: Tensorflow summaries issue]

Comment: Do you see the tensorboard webpage in your browser? Does it say anything there?

Comment: @YaoZhang I see do see the tensorboard webpage in my browser, but when I go to any tab for example scalar tab I get the message *No scalar data was found. Probable causes: You haven't written any scalar data to your event files. TensorBoard can't find your event files.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that I my log logdir contained the `F:` but tensorflow [uses colon as an seperator](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/456) which is a known bug.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use '' to brace the dir , just use the 
`tensorboard --logdir=dir` 
if you use the `win10` System Operation